# using ASP.NET with SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I have an asp.net site and looking to do some reporting with SSRS. Is there any way to do this? 
If so, are there any good tutorials out there to get started?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version and edition of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.  One of which is to use the SSRS [Report Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251692%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) another way is to use an IFRAME and point to the report - which is the way the [Telerik Silverlight HTML placeholder](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/htmlplaceholder.aspx) works.

Answer (score 1):

very generic question, MS has a ReportViewer class / component which you can host in your ASP.NET page, see here:
[Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=CC96C246-61E5-4D9E-BB5F-416D75A1B9EF)